# generate OnCheckedChanged for custom checkbox

Tags: c#, user-controls, event-handling, controls

I have a custom checkbox control that inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Control
and it hasn't CheckedChanged event. I want to implement CheckedChange same as dot net native CheckBox. How can I do it well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inheriting fromn Control, not CheckBox, so the solution is similar to the one proposed by Frigik, but it's not exactly that one.

First of all you have to define the event in your class, i.e.:

```
public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;
```

In this way every developer using your control can subscribe/unsubscribe to the event. This is not enough, since the event will never be triggered. To do so, you have to define a method to trigger it, and the call this method whenever the state of your control changes:

```
private void RaiseCheckedChanged()
{
    if (CheckedChanged!= null)
        CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Where this method will be called depends on the structure of your control. For instance if you have a property Checked, you could call the method in its setter:

```
public bool Checked
{
    get { return _checked; }
    set 
    { 
        _checked = value; 
        RaiseCheckedChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
CheckBox chkList1 = new CheckBox();
chkList1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);

protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krunal but I think you don't understand my meaning.
I want to define "CheckedChanged" event in event list of my control, that when programmers want to write their code in OnCheckedChange, they can do it so

Comment: Suppose you don't have "CheckedChanged" event and you need it. Unfortunately, System.Windows.Forms.Control doesn't have "CheckedChanged" event in event list

Comment: your question is tell that you are generated custom check box in your `.cs` file and you want generate check box `CheckedChanged` in your `.cs` file `is it right`?  Can put what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class YourCheckBox:CheckBox
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnCheckedChangedCustom;

        protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnCheckedChangedCustom!=null)
            {
                OnCheckedChangedCustom(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
        }
    }
```